# Excluding records from SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Given one or more `owner_ids` (for instance, 2, 4, and 6), I would like to return the list of `resources.id` linked to `owners` by `owners_has_resources`.  No problem, I could just do `SELECT DISTINCT ohr.resources_id FROM owners_has_resources ohr WHERE ohr.owners_id IN (2,4,6);`

Now the part I am stuck on.  I would like to return the list of `resources.id` the same as above, but exclude any that are also linked to non-deleted owners (as determined by `owners.deleted!=true`) where the link is not deleted (as determined by `owners_has_resources.deleted!=true`)

It can be assumed that `owners.deleted` is `true` for all the originally provided `owners_ids` (i.e. 2, 4, 6)

For instance, given `owners_ids` 2 and 4, I should return `resources_id` 2 and 3.  Note that I meant to say `deleted=TRUE` indicates it was deleted, but since answers have been posted that used the previous, I won't be editing the question. Instead, the truth table below shows `owner_not_deleted` and `resource_not_deleted`.

```
+-----------+-------------------+--------------+----------------------+
| owners_id | owner_not_deleted | resources_id | resource_not_deleted |
+-----------+-------------------+--------------+----------------------+
|         2 | FALSE             |            1 | TRUE                 |
|         2 | FALSE             |            2 | TRUE                 |
|         4 | FALSE             |            2 | TRUE                 |
|         4 | FALSE             |            3 | TRUE                 |
|         5 | TRUE              |            1 | FALSE                |
|         5 | TRUE              |            2 | TRUE                 |
|         7 | TRUE              |            2 | FALSE                |
+-----------+-------------------+--------------+----------------------+

owners
- id (INT PK)
- name, etc
- deleted (true/false)

resources
- id (INT PK)
- name, etc

owners_has_resources
- owners_id (INT PK REFERENCES owners.id)
- resources_id (INT PK REFERENCES resources.id)
- deleted (true/false)
```

Comment: What's your `users` table? Are is this table linked to the others?

Comment: Sorry, typo. That should be `owners`.  I will update.

Comment: It seems pretty obvious what you need. But I will give the benefit of the doubt. Can you show a little data sample. Just so I can be sure of what you are asking please?

Comment: @JorgeCampos  Working on it.  My actual query is actually a little bit more, and I hope I didn't overly simplify it above.

Comment: As it current is the answer from Wistar seems to solve it. But I feel that it is i bit more complicated than that :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos  Please see my edited post.  Wistar's solution doesn't work on all cases.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
SELECT DISTINCT ohr.resources_id 
FROM owners_has_resources ohr 
JOIN owners o ON ohr.owners_id = o.id
WHERE ohr.owners_id IN (2,4,6)
AND (o.deleted = FALSE OR ohr.deleted = FALSE);
```

Comment: I think it needs to be `o.deleted = FALSE
OR ohr.deleted = FALSE`, but that seems to lead to other problems.

Comment: @user1032531 I made the change. What problem do you face with that query?

Comment: Given your first query and my fictional data on my edited post, it would return resources_id #3 only, and your edited query would return #1, #2, and #3.  It should only return #2 and #3.

Comment: @user1032531 I am not sure I get what you are looking for. The first and second line of your table are virtually identical but for the `resources_id`. Why then should resources_id #2 be returned but not resources_id #1?

Comment: Because Owner #5 still needs it.  Owner #5 hasn't been deleted, nor has its link to Resource #2 been tagged as deleted.

Answer (score 0):

First you pick the data you want then you only select those which are not referenced by non deleted owners in the `NOT EXISTS` block

```
SELECT DISTINCT ohr.resources_id 
FROM owners_has_resources ohr 
JOIN owners o ON ohr.owners_id = o.id
WHERE ohr.owners_id IN (2,4,6)
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM owners_has_resources ohr2 
    JOIN owners o2 ON ohr2.owners_id = o2.id
    WHERE ohr2.deleted=FALSE 
    AND o2.deleted=FALSE
    AND ohr.resources_id=ohr2.resources_id 
)
```

Comment: Thanks StephaneM.  Will need to mule this over for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ohr1.resources_id
FROM owners_has_resources ohr1
LEFT OUTER JOIN owners_has_resources ohr2 ON ohr2.resources_id=ohr1.resources_id AND ohr2.deleted = TRUE
LEFT OUTER JOIN owners o ON o.id=ohr2.owners_id AND ohr2.deleted = TRUE
WHERE ohr1.owners_id IN (2,4,6) AND o.id IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT ohr1.resources_id
FROM owners_has_resources ohr1
LEFT OUTER JOIN owners_has_resources ohr2 ON ohr2.resources_id=ohr1.resources_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN owners o ON o.id=ohr2.owners_id
WHERE ohr1.owners_id IN (2,4,6) AND o.id IS NULL AND ohr2.deleted = TRUE AND ohr2.deleted = TRUE;
```

I would appreciate any comments on whether one approach is better than the other.